# Vesta CP upgrade PHP version to 5.6 (CentOS 64bit)

Tags: linux, laravel-4, self-hosting, centos6.5, php-5.6

Default Vesta CP 0.9.8 comes with PHP5.4 which causes me problems on my Laravel 4.2 website.
How can i upgrade php version of self hosted Vesta CP from 5.4 to latest 5.6 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default PHP version of vesta CP 0.9.8 is PHP5.4

First stop your web server

If NGINX

`service nginx stop`

If Apache

`service httpd stop`

Then remove php

`yum remove php -y`

Add related repositories

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm`

enabling remi for 'remi' and 'remi-php56'

`nano /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and change the enabled value from 0 to 1

Install php56

`yum install php php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-gd php-imap php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysql php-pdo php-soap php-tidy php-xml php-xmlrpc php-pecl-apc phpMyAdmin roundcubemail php-opcache php-xdebug -y`

reset the links

`mv -f /etc/roundcubemail/db.inc.php.rpmsave /etc/roundcubemail/db.inc.php
mv -f /etc/roundcubemail/main.inc.php.rpmsave /etc/roundcubemail/main.inc.php
mv -f /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.rpmsave /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

Start your web server.

This worked on my server.

Originally taken from [here](http://hasin.me/2014/06/03/upgrading-php-to-5-5-in-a-centos-6-server-with-vesta-cp/).

Comment: Actually you don't need to remove php. So you can skip the `yum remove php -y` step and after enabling remi repo run `yum update php` to upgrade the installed php 5.4 with php 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

I use this command and it's working fine on centos 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php-common --replace-with=php56w-common
```